# Accessing dataframe information and use ddply or anything similar to perform some function

Tags: dataframe, rstudio

I want to use the following data.frame

```
   split_types   Xcenter Ycenter zCenter
1.     type_1       10       20      30
2.     type_2       15       25      35
```

and i want to extract Xcenter,Ycenter & zCenter  based on the split_types and use them accordingly

I tried using ddply like this just to get sum of the Xcenter, yCenter & zCenter

```
ddply(data.frame, .(split_types), summarize, k = sum(Xcenter,yCenter,zCenter))
```

It gives an Error saying that sum cannot be applied on factors. Hope you understand what i want to do.

Expected output should be

```
   split_types   k
1.   type_1      60
2.   type_2      75
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new column k with the sum results, and then select split_types and k:

```
df <- your_data_frame
df[,'k'] <- df[,'Xcenter'] + df[,'yCenter'] + df[,'zCenter']
new_df <- df[,c('split_types','k')]
```